# Error in onActivityResult after taking image in camera

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

I am trying to take a picture using the camera and display the same. While the same works fine in the emulator it does not work in my samsung j5 prime device

Here is my code:

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { cameraIntent ->

cameraIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                        val pictureFile : File? = try {
                            getPictureFile()
                        } catch (ex: IOException) {
                            Toast.makeText(this,
                                "Photo file can't be created, please try again",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            null
                        }
                        pictureFile ?.also {
                            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                                this,
                                "$packageName.fileprovider",
                                it
                            )

cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA)
                        }
                    }
                }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        val imgFile = File(pictureFilePath)
        Log.d("MyMessage",data.toString())
        if (data != null) {
            if (imgFile.exists())
            {
                previewbox.setImageBitmap(setScaledBitmap())
                prescripPreview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                filepath = photoURI
            }
        }


    }
```

When I use an emulator the log returns intent { } 
But in the device the log returns null. What is the issue here?

Comment: Are you holding onto `pictureFile` in your saved instance state? "When I use an emulator the log returns intent { } But in the device the log returns null. What is the issue here?" -- there is no issue with that. Since you are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, there is no need for a camera app to return an `Intent` to you.

Comment: Yes I am. So that the file can be . uploaded later on if the user wants. So does that mean that the data not null check should be done away with?

Comment: "So does that mean that the data not null check should be done away with?" -- yes. After all, you are not using `data` for anything inside that `if` block.